# How can I merge cells in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe like this.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(03/25/93, 03, 25, 93)]    NaN     [(03/25, 03, 25)]   NaN
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(6/18/85, 6, 18, 85)]  NaN     [(6/18, 6, 18)]     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(7/8/71, 7, 8, 71)]    [(7/8/71, 7, 8, 71)]    [(8/71, 8, 71)]     NaN
3   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(9/27/75, 9, 27, 75)]  NaN     [(9/27, 9, 27)]     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(2/6/96, 2, 6, 96)]    [(2/6/96, 2, 6, 96)]    [(6/96, 6, 96)]     NaN
5   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(7/06/79, 7, 06, 79)]  [(7/06/79, 7, 06, 79)]  [(7/06, 7, 06)]     NaN
6   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(5/18/78, 5, 18, 78)]  NaN     [(5/18, 5, 18)]     NaN
7   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(10/24/89, 10, 24, 89)]    NaN     [(10/24, 10, 24)]   [9080]
8   NaN     NaN     NaN     [(3/7/86, 3, 7, 86)]    [(3/7/86, 3, 7, 86)]    [(7/86, 7, 86)]     NaN
```

I have to merge it by omitting the Nan values and take only one cell from the row by keeping the index unchanged.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Merge it with what? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The desired output is  0  ([03/25/93], 03, 25, 93)